# Add multiple markers in callback function on Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, google-maps-markers, parse-platform

I'm trying to add several markers on a Google Maps.
However, just the last is added. It's probably due to deleting reference but I don't get how javascript works. I use Parse to manage my data, it works like Backbone.js

`query.find()` returns a promise object containing two Foo objects. I call buildMarker (because I don't manage to build the marker at initialization) and addToMap, but at the end, just the last is added.
Could you explain why it works like that ?

I show you my code :

```
$(function(){
var Foo = Parse.Object.extend({
    className: "Foo",
    initialize: function(){
    },

    marker: new google.maps.Marker(),
    buildMarker: function(){
        var pos = this.get("position");
        this.marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(pos.latitude, pos.longitude));   
    },
    addToMap: function(map){
        this.marker.setMap(map);
    },
    removeFromMap: function(map){
        this.marker.setMap(null)
    }
});

var query = new Parse.Query(Foo);

promise = query.find({
    success: function(results){
        alert("success : " + results.length);
    }
});

promise.then(function(foo){
    foo.forEach(function(a){
        a.buildMarker();
        a.addToMap(map);
    });
});

});
```

Thank you very much,

Comment: where's your code to create the marker? keep an array of markers and push new ones into it rather than reusing the same one

Comment: Marker is contained in the object Foo. Foo::buildMarker() sets the marker's position and Foo::addToMap() sets the map. So every markers is stored into the "collection" `promise`. I don't want to dissociate markers and Foo object...